# Barra de Navegacion Botones Flotantes

Tags: html, css

Les comento, en mi localhost si yo habro la pagina local se ven bien pero yo la carge en mi host 000webhost y los botones se pusieron flotando no se que paso pero como que subieron y se quedaron levitando, cosa cuando abro mi pagina local no ocurre

la pagina es http://gruposcoutpapafrancisco.tk/

no se si me logro a entender.

Dejo foto como se ve local y como se ve mal en la pagina

Local: así se debería de ver
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yq5oh.png

Pagina:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3UpB.png

Comment: Mirando la consola (pulsa F12 en tu navegador) aparecen varios errores de javascript. Dudo que tengan una gran relación con tu problema, pero indica que no estás depurando tu código y quizás esos errores causen efectos colaterales indeseados.

Comment: Por cierto, si muevo estilos/estilos.css por debajo de bootstrap.min.css se ve bien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo solucionas aplicando margin global en a:

```
dl, ol, ul {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

o en estilos.css:

```
.nav__list {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 0;
```

}